# Are Azure Cosmos backups charged per region?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, cost-management

Does Azure charge you per region when performing periodical Cosmos backups?

Based on their calculator it seems that's what they do. I have a single write region and a single read region and it looks like I will be charged for both regions when I enable backups.

Also, how does the "backup restore redundancy" (GRS, ZRS, and LRS) work into pricing for backups? It's an option in the Azure Portal but their calculator does not account for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You will be charged for both regions.
However, 2 periodic backups per region are free. You are charged only if you opt for more than 2 backups.

By default, Azure Cosmos DB stores periodic mode backup data in geo-redundant storage (GRS). Updating backup storage redundancy to ZRS or LRS will not have any impact on backup storage pricing.